# How to convert raw url to hyperlink?

Tags: functions, links

I have a custom field with raw urls and I want to convert them to hyperlinks. So I used this code:

```
<?php $text = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'Links', TRUE );
echo make_clickable( $text ); ?>
```

The problem with this code is it doesn't work with urls that contains spaces in them. How can I make it work for urls with spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URL-encode spaces beforehand:

```
make_clickable( str_replace( ' ', '%20', $text ) );
```